# git rebase fails with "Fatal: out of memory" error during rebase because of large files

Tags: git

Here is the scenario: 
git repo contains master.  Branch named "fixed_dependencies" created.  Off of "fixed_dependencies", another branch "included_externals" is created where some large files (over 1GB each) are added.  Off of "included_externals", another branch "distributed_comms" is created.  When we go to rebase "distributed_comms" with master, those files added in the previous commit/branch cause a "Fatal: out of memory" error.

Question:
How do we merge/rebase the "distributed_comms" back in to master (in order to preserve repo history), rather than reverting to master and simply copying the new files from the branches (minus the large problematic files, which were a mistake to add) in to a new branch and rebasing that new branch with master?  Is there a way to tell git to disclude those large files in its replay effort?

Comment: Just `git rm` the files if you think they were a mistake to add?

Comment: The git rm would only be for the current commit, though, correct?  So when the replay happens, the files will still be seen because there were commits between the master and this current.  That is my understanding, anyway.

Comment: Probably the *easiest* way is to copy the repository to a machine that has more memory and thus doesn't run out, or add more memory to your existing machine. The second-easiest may be to use [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to discard the big files. (You might find the easy-ness of these two inverted.)

Comment: I gave the BFG a go and it seems to do a bang-up job of simply removing unwanted file(s), although I haven't tested any further to ensure it does not wreak havoc to the repo in terms of side effects  :)